# Why does [imageView respondsToSelector: @selector (contentScaleFactor:)] always is equal to NO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I set base sdk 4.1 and ios deployment target = ios4.1. The contentScaleFactor is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

```
if ( [imageView respondsToSelector: @selector (contentScaleFactor:)] == YES )
{
    imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
}
```

Why do i always get NO ?

Comment: Why do you even check for this if your deployment target is 4.0 anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not respond to `contentScaleFactor:` because `contentScaleFactor` is a property, with the following accessors:

```
- (CGFloat)contentScaleFactor
- (void)setContentScaleFactor:(CGFloat)
```

There is no other method with the name `contentScaleFactor` that accepts a single parameter (marked by the `:`).

So, the selectors available are `contentScaleFactor` and `setContentScaleFactor:`. You are probably looking for `setContentScaleFactor:`, that's what the setter is called.

Change your code to this:

```
if ( [imageView respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentScaleFactor:)] == YES )
{
    // Or as bbum says, use [imageView setContentScaleFactor:1.0];
    imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly;  I'd suggest that instead of dot syntax, Voloda2 should use `[imageView setContentScaleFactor: 1.0];` for clarity in context of the `respondsToSelector:` test.

Comment: I get warning in 3.2 sdk. [imageView setContentScaleFactor:1.0]; warning: 'UIView' may not respond to '-setContentScaleFactor:'
How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: I get error in 3.2 sdk.  imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0; error: request for member 'contentScaleFactor' in something not a structure or union

Comment: In Xcode 4.2, using dot notation in an error (not a warning). The workaround remains the same: send the `setContentScaleFactor:` message instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because the selector `contentScaleFactor:` is different from the selector `contentScaleFactor`, and neither corresponds to the property setter's selector, which is `setContentScaleFactor:`. You just need to do this:

```
if ([imageView respondsToSelector: @selector(contentScaleFactor)])
{
    imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
}
```

Note the `:` is gone from the selector declaration. Also, note that setting your scale factor to `1.0` will not take advantage of the Retina Display.

Comment: Your code effectively says "check for selector `contentScaleFactor` and then call the method with selector `setContentScaleFactor:`".  It works by coincidence only.

Comment: I am aware of this. The two selectors appear at the same time (4.0) so I was keeping the code changes simple. Note the paragraph above the code sample where I acknowledge the difference.